# reference any one of a range of my Classes with one variable type?

Tags: c#, class, variables

pretty new with C#, probably an easy question for most of you I just have little experience with this.

lets say i have a class which creates and handles the model, control, sound etc. for a space ship, so:

```
Ship myShip = new Ship();
```

Creates the Ship, and i can see it and all is good there, i can access its variables with 'ship', and i could make another and call it something else.. but if i had another Class which was for a.. Battleship.. say another for a fighter.. the AI for the ships in a battle have a 'target'. So i could use:

```
Ship target;
```

and 'target' will reference the current target which may change to another instance of Ship, but my question, is there a variable type which could handle any of these classes, like say the target switches from an instance of Ship, to a Battleship. I would get an error that it cant convert from type Battleship to Ship.

if there is no such variable type is there an easier way to do this instead of a different variable for each type of Class that may become a target?

and just incase im not real clear.. I basically want this to work without errors:

```
WhatsThisHere target = new Ship();
target = new DifferentTypeOfShip();
```

Thankss!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is create an interface from which all of your ships implement. This way you can create common functions / methods (Note that the interface cannot implement any code within the functions, because an interface is abstract) and implement these in your classes. For example.

```
public interface IShipInterface
{
    //any common properties here

    //any common methods/functions here
    void Target();
    void AnythingElseYouNeed();
}

public class Ship : IShipInterface
{
    //fields

    public Ship()
    {
        //constructor
    }

    public void Target()
    {
        //implement your ship Target method here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void AnythingElseYouNeed()
    {
        //implement other function code here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class BattleShip : IShipInterface
{
    //fields 

    public BattleShip()
    {
        //constructor
    }

    public void Target()
    {
        //here is your battleship targetting, which could be completely different from your ship targetting.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void AnythingElseYouNeed()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

From here you can create them like so;

```
IShipInterface ship = new Ship();
IShipInterface battleShip = new BattleShip();
```

This has advantages because all of your ships can then be referred to by type ShipInterface, for example in a foreach loop

```
foreach (IShipInterface ship in ShipList.OfType<BattleShip>())
        {
            //all your battleships
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help (and everyone else :D)

Loop will also be very useful..

Comment: No problem : ) if you need more help, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 3):

Use an interface and inherit `Ship` from it. Then your targets don't need to be ships only.

```
interface ITargetable
{
    //
}

class Ship : ITargetable
{
    //
}
```

In another class you would then only use `ITargetable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create

```
public class Ship {
   //Common behaviour and parameters for every ship in the world
}

public class BattleShip : Ship {
   // get basic Ship behavior and adds it's 
   // own battle specific properties and functions
}
```

so in the code you do like:

```
Ship me = new BattleShip(); 
Ship enimy = new BattleShip(); 
me.Target = enimy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let all types that look like a ship derive from `Ship`:

```
public class BattleShip : Ship
{

}
```